# How to send trc20 usdt using tronweb in node.js

Tags: tron

I want to send trc20 usdt, btc to other address using tronweb.
Could anyone please help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I've just answered it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159498/10790608)